# How to increment all dates by 1 year for testing bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Could you please help me increment the year as shown below, I am really lost.The official tutorials aren't clear. I'm a noob just trying to learn. 
Actual

```
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2015-06-01 |
| 2015-06-02 |
| 2015-06-03 |
| ...        |
| 2016-07-11 |
+------------+
```

Expected

```
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2016-06-01 |
| 2016-06-02 |
| 2016-06-03 |
| ...        |
| 2017-07-11 |
+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_add), you can use the `DATE_ADD()` function, it adds a specified time interval to a date. The syntax is :

```
DATE_ADD(date_expression, INTERVAL INT64_expr date_part)
```

Notice that the first argument in the expression is a *DATE* and the second is a *INT64*. Therefore, if your field is not a *DATE* format, you can use [`CAST()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting) to parse it to *DATE* format.

Your query syntax will be as below:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CAST(your_field as DATE), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS date_increased
FROM table_source
```

An alternative would be using the `UPDATE` method, which you can read more about [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data). This method updates the selected field_values directly in the source table. Your syntax would be as follows:

```
UPDATE
  `source_table`
SET
  date_field = DATE_ADD(date_field, INTERVAL 1 year)
WHERE
  TRUE
```

Notice that the difference between these two methods lies on the fact that the first one creates a new view and the second modifies the source table.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE "2015-06-01", INTERVAL 1 YEAR) as one_year_later;
```

Comment: But this is per date, I have 500 rows.

Comment: replace the first param with your column name

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, might not be the most optimal way. Answering so that others facing the same hurdle might be able to refer to this.

> Update `[table_name]` set your_col_date=cast(
>   CONCAT('2020',SUBSTR(cast(your_col_date AS STRING),5)) as date) where
>   your_col_date>2018-01-01 ;